# How to set a different ZSH theme when using TTY?

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh, tty

I'm using agnoster theme on my terminal and it looks pretty bad when I need to use a tty.

Already tried this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581171 without sucess,

```
case $TERM in
  urxvt*)
    ZSH_THEME="agnoster";;
  *)
    ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell";;
esac
```

and this:

```
if [ "$TERM" = "urxvt" ]; then
    ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
else
    ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
fi
```

In both methods I get only the robbyrussell theme in urxvt and in tty, also tried some other things some weeks ago but can't remember the snippets of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, took me 4 days to realize that running $TERM in terminal would give me the answer.

```
if [ "$TERM" = "rxvt-unicode-256color" ]; then
    ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
else
    ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
fi
```

But I think that going this way bellow is even better if you end up changing your default terminal emulator or like doing "terminal-hopping"

```
if [ "$TERM" = "linux" ]; then
    ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
else
    ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
fi
```